# Value Field not Displaying Values when using VBA to make a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

The code does not cause an error and a table with the correct row and column fields are created. Nothing appears in the value field though.

```
'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Rev by Facility")
    With .PivotFields("Facility")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    'Insert Column Fields
    With .PivotFields("Revenue")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    'Insert Data Field
    With .PivotFields("SubTotal 2")
        .Orientation = xlValuesField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlSum
        .Name = "Sum of SubTotal 2"
    End With
End With
```

This is only part of the code, the above code should not cause the value field to not appear. The data source of the pivot table includes the column and all the data I want to appear in the value field.

Comment: Make sure that your lines of code are indented according to the above `With` statement

Comment: They are now lined up but it didn't change the result of running the Macro.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what it looks like versus what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not having your lines properly indented can cause all sorts of issues.  Try this

```
    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Rev by Facility")
        With .PivotFields("Facility")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    'Insert Column Fields
        With .PivotFields("Revenue")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    'Insert Data Field
        With .PivotFields("SubTotal 2")
            .Orientation = xlValuesField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlSum
            .Name = "Sum of SubTotal 2"
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: Try referencing the Worksheet specifically instead of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: No change again. Its odd because it isn't like it is pulling SubTotal 2 into values and not displaying the values, it just isn't picking up SubTotal 2 right after it picks up two other fields using the same method.

Comment: Are "SubTotal2" values numeric or text.  Like when you click on the cells that you grabbing the information from are they text formatted.  I would take a look at this if I were you:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Comment: I read that article and tried that method of inserting the Value field too which yielded the same results. The SubTotal 2 cells are all general and I tried it with them as numbers as well.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It's probably something very simple that I am missing.

Comment: I've been staring at it for quite some time and even found the same exact question with the same coding asked on this website and the correction that fixed that one results in no change for this.

Comment: My recommendation would be to walk away, clear your head, and pick up something else for a bit

Answer (score 0):

To define a pivot field as "value field", you have to use `xlDataField`.

```
.Orientation = xlDataField
```

Just in case:
The often called "filter fields" have the orientation `xlPageField`.

Comment: @kev12222 Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please do me a favor and mark the checkbox beneath it (see [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). If not, don't hesitate to comment here below it.